# Extract an IP address from a custom text file using Bash

Tags: bash, grep

I have a text file with following contents:

```
NAME                       REGION        ADDRESS         STATUS
instance-name              europe-west1  1.2.3.4         IN_USE
instance-name-2            europe-west1  1.3.2.4         IN_USE
instance-name-3            europe-west1  1.5.3.2         IN_USE
```

I want to extract the IP address only from *"instance-name-3"*. How would it be possible in that situation?

For example, this allows me to find all the IP addresses, but I only want the *"instance-name-3"* one:

```
grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0
-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" iplist.txt
```

Comment: Use `grep` and `cut` and maybe `tr` with squeeze

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pBit more compact alternative to @waymobetta's solution

```
awk '/^instance-name-3  /{print $3}' your_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @tinkertime, sounds easier than I thought, but never played with this kind of stuff. ;)

Comment: That would print $3 for `instance-name-31` too. `$1=="instance-name-3"`

Answer (score 3):

If column 1 is `instance-name-3` then print column 3:

```
awk '$1=="instance-name-3" {print $3}' file
```

Output:

```
1.5.3.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
cat your_file.txt | grep 'instance-name-3' | awk '{print $3}'
```

This will pull out only the IP address (column 3) of the row with name `instance-name-3`

*result:*

[image]