# Print a single portion from specific rows of text in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a .out file with ~10,000 lines. In the middle of the file I have a bunch of rows that contain values that I want to print.

For example:

```
...~5000 lines here...   
VALUE 1 429.62 a 394.55 b 865.66 c  
bla-bla-bla1  
bla-bla-bla2   
bla-bla-bla3  
VALUE 2 535.55 a 591.14 b 152.88 c   
bla-bla-bla4   
bla-bla-bla5   
VALUE 3 5015.2 a 590.34 b 41.444 c   
bla-bla-bla6  
....~5000 lines until the end~...
```

I would like the following to be printed (only the bold text values):

```
865.66   
152.88   
41.444
```

So far I could do:

```
grep -r "VALUE" filename
```

And that returns:

```
VALUE 1 429.62 a 394.55 b 865.66 c  
VALUE 2 535.55 a 591.14 b 152.88 c  
VALUE 3 5015.2 a 590.34 b 41.444 c
```

What can I do to get my desired output? My goal is to be able to copy and paste the printed output in a spreadsheet, without any extra stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54975477/3776858

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**awk** - print 7 field in lines with string VALUE

```
awk '/^VALUE/{print $7}' filenmae
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `-r` for grep, if you have only one file?

If you want to do it with grep (instead of using awk, as others have suggested): Selecting a grepped field can be done using `cut`:

```
grep ^VALUE filename | cut -d ' ' -f 7
```

The ^ ensures that only those lines are picked where VALUE is at the start of the line.

This solution assumes that there is exactly one space between the fields. If you want to treat a sequence of spaces like a single one, you would have to do

```
grep ^VALUE filename | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 7
```